# makefile with multiple headers and namespace

Tags: c++, makefile

I am using a public c++ package that has various source files.
I compiled main.cpp which refers to various headers and uses a user-defined namespace with following code:

```
g++ -g main.cpp nmssmsoftsusy.cpp decays.cpp /path/config.h -o main
```

where main.cpp is

```
#include "main.h"
#include "nmssmsoftsusy.h"
#include "decays.h"

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

using namespace softsusy;

int main() {
  /// Sets up exception handling
  signal(SIGFPE, FPE_ExceptionHandler);
```

Then I got errors such as

> undefined reference to `FPE_ExceptionHandler(int)'

There are several errors of this kind even after I change .h to .cpp files or including softsusy.h.

Can I ask you for the source of error in my compile command or for a suggestion of contents in makefile that i can try next time?

Please notice that I am new to run the code using makefile and it would be amazing if you give or suggest me a brief explanation of how to organize makefile. Thanks.

Comment: Find out where `FPE_ExceptionHandler` is defined and link that in. From peeking the documentation I expect something like `utils.cpp`.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. but after including utils.cpp, i found more errors of the same kind that requiring further linkings of several .cpp files. I guess if i follow the errors i need to link all the source files in the src folder. should i do that?

Comment: Also can I ask you for the order of each cpps in g++ commands? for instance type utils.cpp before main.cpp etc

Comment: I'd expect a library to first be compiled independently into a .lib, which then gets linked by users. As for the order of .cpp files, I'm not sure it matters, but if it does it usually has the dependent files first.

Comment: @Quentin Can I ask you for the way to compile all the files in a folder(called src) and link them at once (using makefile)?

Comment: Yes, using *glob expressions*. But that's when you go back to Reading The Fantastic Manual ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to compile the package itself and get the libraries, which your program link against later:

What you have to do:

```
aclocal
./configure
make
```

After that you have a lot of libraries like this ( static ones )

```
./.libs/libsoft.a
./.libs/libtsil.a
./.libs/libsupermodel.a
```

or this ones ( dynamic ones ):

```
./.libs/libsoft.so.0
./.libs/libsupermodel.so.0
./.libs/libsoft.so.0.0.0
./.libs/libtsil.so.0
./.libs/libtsil.so.0.0.0
./.libs/libsupermodel.so.0.0.0
./.libs/libsupermodel.so
./.libs/libtsil.so
./.libs/libsoft.so
```

If you now want to compile your *own* main.cpp project, you simply have
to link against the libraries as needed. I can compile and link your main.cpp with the following command:

```
g++ main.cpp -I softsusy-4.1.1/src/ -L/home/krud/softsusy/softsusy-4.1.1/.libs -lsoft -ltsil -lsupermodel -o go
```

All that is written in the INSTALL and README files of the package and also in the docs of the package.

If you have no idea how to link against a library, you have to start a new question because it has really nothing to do with Makefile and nothing todo with the mentioned source package.

Info: I did it on my pc a minute ok by simply downloading version 4.1.1 as tgz. Unpacking and the 3 steps ahead I got everything ready to use. Only the `aclocal` was needed as addition,m because my box has a newer autotools version.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try to create a Makefile. 
There you can compile the nmn.. to an object file and the decays.cpp to an object file. Finally you can compile your main.cpp. For a detailed explanation refer to http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/