# how to link a library(lib.a) to a cpp file in compiling?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker

The question i had previously in ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136979/makefile-with-multiple-headers-and-namespace/50138425#50138425)) needs to be requestioned with a proper title. Here I ask my problem in this post.

As suggested in the link above, after

```
./configure > make > make install > aclocal > make
```

library files including libsoft.a and libsoft.so were created in "softsusy-4.1.1/.libs".

Also in "softsusy-4.1.1/src/.libs" folder, all necessary .o files wree already created whose .cpp files are included/refered in main.cpp.

In an attempt to compile main.cpp, i tried

```
g++ -g main.cpp nmssmsoftsusy.cpp decays.cpp /path/config.h -o main
g++ -g -Wall -L/path/softsusy-4.1.1/src/.libs -llibsoft main.cpp -o test
g++ -g -Wall -llibsoft main.cpp -o main
```

where main.cpp is

```
#include "main.h"
#include "nmssmsoftsusy.h"
#include "decays.h"

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

using namespace softsusy;

int main() {
  /// Sets up exception handling
  signal(SIGFPE, FPE_ExceptionHandler);
```

Then I got errors such as

> undefined reference to `FPE_ExceptionHandler(int)'

for the first and second trials, and an error that it doesn't know libsoft for the last trial:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsoft

There are several errors of this kind even after I change .h to .cpp files or including softsusy.h.

Can I ask you how to appropriately link .o files(whose .cpp files are included in main()) or any other ways to run main.cpp?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `g++ main.cpp -lsoft -o main`

Comment: You need to figure out in which library is the symbol defined. Until you know for certain which libraries you should link with, trying random things is unlikely to be productive.

Comment: Libraries should appear last on the compiler command line. For .o files the order isn't really significant.

Comment: You seem to be moitoring your question. Did my idea work for you?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for advice but it only shows an error message "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsoft"

Comment: Sorry, are you absolutely sure you tried what I suggested and not something else? There is no `-llibsoft` in my command.

Comment: no there isn't. but even -lsoft doesn't work for the same reason

Comment: Then try `g++ main.cpp -L/path/softsusy-4.1.1/src/.libs -lsoft -o main`.

Comment: it doesn't work neither.

Comment: What is the error message? "can't find ..." or "undefined reference to ..."?

Comment: as spcified in the OP, for g++ main.cpp -L/path/softsusy-4.1.1/src/.libs -lsoft -o main, the error is simply "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsoft". without linking, a lot of errors of type "undefined reference to ..."

Comment: Then double check that `/path/softsusy-4.1.1/src/.libs` is the correct path and it does contain `libsoft.a` and `libsoft.so`. Keep in mind that the path is probably case-sensitive. I can't image any other reason for it to not work besides the incorrect path. (To clarify, I asked to make sure the error hasn't changed.)

Comment: Thank you for comments. i moved all the files in ./libs folder to newly created folder and "cannot find" error disappeared. but instead "undefined reference to `higherorder'" message appeared.

Comment: Which means that this library is linked correctly, but you need some other library as well. Check `.libs` for more `.a` or `.so` files and link them too. Keep in mind that relative library order in the command might matter.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you. my problem was solved with your suggestion. I added all lib files -lsoft -ltsil etc. Thanks!